# How to deploy angular app to laravel forge

Tags: angular, server, forge

I have laravel forge for server management, I was able to deploy nodeJs by following this article https://www.magjoyner.com/posts/2018-08-08-using-laravel-forge-for-non-php-projects/  but wondered if can I do the same for angular app, I didn't find any clear tutorial how to do this, please advice